# Jump from inner if statement to outer else

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a code that evaluates the given values `a` and `b` several times. If a condition is matched, different stuff is done. It can be the case that after varying `b`, the condition is unmatched and then, in a logical way, it should do what was stated before in the `else`.

Here's a simplified part of the algorithm:

```
if a > b:
    # do stuff 0
    b += x  # statement that varies b

    if a > b:
        # do stuff 1
    else:
        # do stuff 2
        # now b > a so it matches the first if statement and should jump to first else
else:
    # do stuff 2
```

[image]

How can I do that without writing the same piece of code under several `elses`?

Comment: Can't you use a function for "do stuff 2"? Functions are jumps to locations of code

Comment: this would be the workaround, but not the solution itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't nest the statements; check if `a > b`, then check if `a` is *still* greater than `b` after the possible update of `b`.

```
# If this is true, a > b is true (assuming x is nonnegative)
if a > b:
    b = b + x

if a > b:
    # do stuff 1
else:
    # do stuff 2
```

If the first `a > b` failed, the second one will as well.

Comment: So add `# do stuff 0` to the first `if` statement, before updating `b`. This doesn't really change the structure of your code.

Comment: `do stuff 0` and `b = b + x` constitutes a single basic block: you can contract the two into a single node without introducing or eliminating any branches to your flow chart. If `a > b` is false the first time, it's going to be false the second time as well, since `b` hasn't changed, resulting in the execution of `do stuff 2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a `GoTo` statement as per the [*docs*](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-is-there-no-goto) :

```
class Stuff2(Exception): pass

try:
    a = 2
    b = 1

    if a > b:
        print("Doing stuff 0")
        x = int(input("Enter the value of x: "))
        b += x

        if a > b:
            print("Doing stuff 1")
        else:
            raise Stuff2()

    else:
        raise Stuff2()

except Stuff2:
    print("Doing stuff 2")
```

Test/Output :

```
Doing stuff 0
Enter the value of x:  2
Doing stuff 2
```

Comment: **NB**: .. that’s usually considered an abuse of goto anyway. Use sparingly !

Comment: *"that’s usually considered an abuse of goto anyway"* - Says/considers who?

Comment: Obviously not me. that's what the docs say, word for word.

Comment: No, it says that about *"jump into the middle of a loop"*, which you're not doing.

Comment: The flow diagram does not provide sufficient information about the OP algorithm. Perhaps they are utilizing loops, right? Anyway, my answer is just an attempt to address a problem I often find myself in.

Comment: Still misrepresentimg what the doc says. And the OP wouldn't be using this to jump into the middle of a loop, either. Because as the doc says, this doesn’t allow you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this can helps you and I understand correctly your questions, use a variable with boolean True/False, change status inside and check it outside. Set it a default value at start

```
have_to_do_stuff_2 = False
if a > b:
    print("a > b")
    b += x  # statement that varies b

    if a > b:
        # do stuff 1
    else:
        # do stuff 2
        # now b > a so it matches the first if statement and should jump to first else
        have_to_do_stuff_2 = True

else:
    have_to_do_stuff_2 = True

if have_to_do_stuff_2:
    # do stuff 2
```

Comment: This doesn't work if `a > b` fails first time. You meant to invert `have_to_do_stuff_2` and set it `False` only in the inner `if`.

Comment: if `a < b` it should directly jump to an else statement

Comment: Not if there isn't one.

Comment: Edited, my mind is overload

Comment: It would be a lot cleaner to set the flag to `True` initially, then only change it (to `False`) when you do "stuff 1".  Less code.

Comment: It can be slightly simpler than that. (see my edited comment)